# Which compilation options should I use to link with Boost using cl.exe?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, hyperlink, visual-studio-2010

I have a program which I would like compile using `cl.exe` on the command-line. This program depends on some boost libraries which I fail to link to.

The error I'm getting is:

```
cl /Fosamples\proxy\proxy.obj /c samples\proxy\proxy.cpp /TP /O2 /EHsc 
  /DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB /DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB /DBOOST_SYSTEM_USE_LIB 
  /DBOOST_USE_WINDOWS_H /DTAP_ID=\"tap0901\" /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 /MD /nologo 
  /Isamples\proxy /Iinclude proxy.cpp
link /nologo /MD /OUT:samples\proxy\proxy.exe /LIBPATH:samples\proxy
  /LIBPATH:lib asiotap.lib libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_47.lib
  libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_47.lib ws2_32.lib gdi32.lib iphlpapi.lib
  advapi32.lib samples\proxy\proxy.obj
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/MD'; ignored 
  asiotap.lib(bootp_builder.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external
  symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl 
  boost::system::system_category(void)"
  (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
```

I compiled Boost, using the following command-line, from the x64 MSVC command prompt:

```
.\b2.exe install toolset=msvc --prefix=C:\Boost-VC-x64
```

If I look inside `libboost_system-vc100-mt-1_47.lib` I can see that:

```
?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ
```

Is exported. But If you look closely it differs a bit from the one in my compilation errors:

```
?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ // The symbol I miss
?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ  // The exported symbol
```

I guess I should either change Boost or my compilation options but fail to figure what to change exactly. Any clue ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use the undname.exe utility to demangle names.  The extra letter is __ptr64.  Sounds to me you're trying to link to a 32-bit build of boost.  Not sure why the linker isn't yelling louder about that, it normally does.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you very much. That was it, indeed. Didn't know about `undname.exe`: definitely useful :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to link Boost 1.52 thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674374/trying-to-link-boost-1-52-thread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigations, I realized that I compiled Boost for a x86 platform where I was linking with a x64 binary.

I thought that compiling Boost inside a Visual Studio x64 command prompt was enough but you actually have to specify:

```
.\b2.exe install toolset=msvc address-model=64 --prefix=C:\Boost-VC-x64
```

To make it work.