# Boost Linker Error: unresolved external symbol

Tags: boost, linker

I built boost latest version (64 bit, msvc-10.0). When using the libraries with my project getting following linker error:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?

Things checked:
1. Libraries are present in the path specified
2. Built 64-bit boost library
3. Using latest boost headers, etc..

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you specified boost with `address-model=64` in b2 command that you used to build boost?

Comment: Command I gave is:   bjam --build-type=complete link=static threading=multi --layout=versioned --with-date_time --with-regex --with-thread address-model=64 runtime-link=shared toolset=msvc-10.0

Comment: try to add `libboost_system_balabala.lib` to your additional dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @jfly. Solved the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to link Boost 1.52 thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674374/trying-to-link-boost-1-52-thread)

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem when using some header-only boost library. The problem is some libraries are themselves header-only, but they depend on `boost.system` which need be linked against your program.