# Linker error with Boost 1.53 and VS 2013 on x64

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, 64-bit

I found this problem on SO and some other places already and it always has to do with linking 32bit libraries on x64 build or vice-versa, ex: [Boost linker error: Unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::get_system_category(void)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066071/boost-linker-error-unresolved-external-symbol-class-boostsystemerror-categ)

```
1>base_pcount.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
1>base_pcount.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAAEBVerror_category@12@XZ)
```

But I am 99% sure I am linking and building x64.

- I am building my program with x64 target
- I am using boost 1.53
- I am using Vs 2013
- I built system lib with the following command (from VS 2013 x64 developer console):

  bootstrap.bat

  .\b2 --build-dir=C:\boost_1_53_0\binaries toolset=msvc-12.0 link=static threading=multi variant=release -address-model=64 architecture=x86 system

So at this point, either boost is not actually building for x64 or my program is not building for x64. Any ideas what could be going wrong here?
Unfortunately nobody provides precompiled binaries for vs 2013 either so I am completely stuck.

Edit: I "solved" this by upgrading to boost 1.57 and using precompiled binaries provided with new release. Seems like boost 1.53 was never meant to be with vs 2013.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to link Boost 1.52 thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674374/trying-to-link-boost-1-52-thread)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but I didn't see your question earlier.

You need to remove the `-` in front of `address-model=64` - it's a property, not an option. So I think you weren't building for 64-bit after all, as `-address-model=64` was taken to be an (probably invalid) option.

Comment: I will try that, seems possible :)